# Android: Overlapping issue with multiple fragments under MainActivity containing Tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, overlapping

I am facing this problem where I have 3 Tabs inside MainActivity and each Tab contains a Fragment. When I click on an item under the drawer to start a new fragment, it gets overlapped on the MainActivity's Tabs view. Below is my code:

```
Fragment currentFragment;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        viewInflate = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_city, container, false);

        return viewInflate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        Intent i;
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            TabLayout tl = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_tabs);
            tl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            showFragment(new HomeFragment());
            setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        }
        if (id == R.id.nav_about_us) {
            TabLayout tl = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_tabs);
            tl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            showFragment(new AboutUsFragment());
            setTitle(R.string.about_us);
        }
        if (id == R.id.nav_favorites) {
            TabLayout tl = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_tabs);
            tl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            showFragment(new FavoritesFragment());
            setTitle(R.string.favorites);
        }
        if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {
            i = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    public void showFragment(Fragment fragment) {

        if (currentFragment != null && fragment.getClass().equals(currentFragment.getClass()))
            return;

        currentFragment = fragment;
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (fragmentManager == null)
            return;

        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        if (ft == null)
            return;

        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
```

Below is the xml code of fragment_city.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/content_background"
    tools:context="com.creationjunkies.fragments.CityFragment">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/cityBargainsRecyclerView"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

And activity_main.xml code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:background="@color/content_background"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.creationjunkies.cities.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/main_tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frameTopAds"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_frame"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/tab_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior" />

            </FrameLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frameAds"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Could you add your Activity XML layout?

Comment: @MuthukrishnanRajendran I've added the XML layout codes now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set fragment background as white.
It will solve the issue.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
tools:context="com.creationjunkies.fragments.CityFragment">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/cityBargainsRecyclerView"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: No, it didn't helped as I've already tried it well before posting this question :)

Comment: Can u please send a screenshot?